# How to connect to remote NFS server to confirm the directories are mounted correctly

Tags: server, client, nfs, nfsclient

I am using my company laptop which is use windows 10 OS and I want to confirm that the nfs server is mounted correctly on remote machine. How can I do this?

How can I install just the nfs client on my machine to connect to this NFS server, or is there any other way that I can achieve this?